# Function that checks whether input value is palindrome or not always returns true

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a program that prints out if a word is a palindrome or not, but for some reason it doesn't work.

When I click the button it says that the word is palindrome even if it is not.
I tried to replace the `inputString` with a variable and it works.
So I think it's a problem of the line `document.getElementById ("word").value`.

```js
var inputString = document.getElementById("word").value;
var textTrue = "It's a palindrome!";
var textFalse = "Sorry, that's not a palindrome.";

//function that return true if the word is palindrome and false if it is not
function isPalindrome(inStr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < inStr.length; i += 1) {
    if (inStr[i] !== inStr[inStr.length - 1 - i]) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
    
/* function that print "the word is palindrome" if the isPalindrome function returns true
or "the word is not palindrome" if the isPalindrome function returns false */
function clickFunction() {
  if (isPalindrome(inputString)) {
    console.log(textTrue);
  } else {
    console.log(textFalse);
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>PALINDROME WORD CHECKER</h1>
</header>

<input class="inputbox" type="word" id="word" placeholder="input">
<button onclick="clickFunction()"> Check! </button>
<script src="code.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can change your input type =" text"

```
<input class="inputbox" type="text" id="word" placeholder="input">
```

js file also

```
function clickFunction() {
var inputString = document.getElementById("word").value;
if (isPalindrome(inputString)) {
    console.log(textTrue);
} else {
    console.log(textFalse);
}
```

}

you get definitely result.

Answer (score 3):

You have to read the content of inputString only after you fill in the text and click on your "Check" button. So You have to move the first line:

```
var inputString = document.getElementById("word").value;
```

into your function:

```
function clickFunction() {
    var inputString = document.getElementById("word").value;
    if (isPalindrome(inputString)) {
        console.log(textTrue);
    } else {
        console.log(textFalse);
    }
}
```

Otherwise, the `inputString` is only read when the page loads and never gets updated with the content of the input, and the textbox's initial value is `""` (empty string), which is a palindrome.